# How to rewrite a URL like http://189.3.xxx.xxx/index.php?p=home

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my URL, but without success. `mod_rewrite` is enabled. I'm using this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep it from looping, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```